# Is the nature of Fantomex's E.V.A. explained in comics?

Tags: comics, marvel, fantomex

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantomex#Powers_and_abilities),

> Fantomex has an external nervous system referred to as E.V.A. He has
>   mentioned that E.V.A. emerged from his mouth during his time in the
>   World and developed into a techno-organic flying saucer-like vessel.
>   The relationship between E.V.A and Fantomex is symbiotic, so if E.V.A.
>   experiences pain when she is not within Fantomex, he will feel it as
>   well. When E.V.A. is separated from his body, Fantomex feels no pain
>   and seems able to ignore most injuries.

I've been reading Uncanny X-Force and it's left me scratching my head with questions like what E.V.A. is, where it/she resides when not in ship form, etc.  While the above explains some of it, it doesn't provide a reference to which comic E.V.A.'s nature is explained in.

**Is E.V.A.'s nature conclusively explained in the comics, and if so, where?**  Any additional information about E.V.A. would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

#### EVA is a symbiotic life-form which acts as a central nervous system for Fantomex. But she is so much more:

- She is a construct created from nanosentinel technology. Comprised of intelligent nanites she is an intelligent, thinking, self-aware organism.

[image]

- She is capable of compressing herself and residing inside of Fantomex. While she is inside, his body is capable of feeling all physical sensory input.
- When EVA is outside of Fantomex, his visual information is reduced to greyscale imaging and he can no longer perceive in color.
- She is capable of expanding herself outside of his body and becoming a vehicle able to carry five humans in flight at as yet undisclosed speeds. During this time, she covers Fantomex's head interacting through some undisclosed interface. She creates an entire environment and super-structure.

[image]

- In close combat, tight quarters, or to enhance his movement, Fantomex may ride her akin to a surfboard

[image]

- While she is outside of Fantomex's body, she is vulnerable to injury and if she is injured, so is Fantomex.
- EVA can function autonomously without direction from Fantomex, is capable of flight and able to project bio-electrical energy to defend herself.
- She has shown the ability to project the "misdirection" immersive illusions even when Fantomex is not present. I theorize she may be the actual source of the power.

[image]